# Group by two columns, take sum, then max

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are three columns: `Id` (char), `Name` (char), and `Score` (int).

First, we group by `Id` and `Name` and add `Score` for each group. Let us call the added score `total_score`.

Then, we group by `Name` and take only the maximum of `total_score` and its corresponding `Id` and `Name`. I've got everything else but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the `Id`. The error I get is

> Column 'Id' is invalid in the select list because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

```
WITH Tmp AS
  (SELECT Id,
          Name,
          SUM(Score) AS total_score
   FROM Mytable
   GROUP BY Id,
            Name)
SELECT Name,  -- Id,
       MAX(total_score) AS max_score
FROM Tmp
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY max_score DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `row_number()` partition by `Name` to your query and get the 1st row (order by `total_score` descending)

```
select  *
from
(
    -- your existing `total_score` query
    SELECT  Id, Name,
            SUM(Score) AS total_score,
            r = row_number() over (partition by Name order by SUM(Score) desc)
    FROM  Mytable
    GROUP BY Id, Name
) d
where   r = 1
```

Comment: such case is not mention or highlighted by OP. If it does happens, it can be easily handle by using `dense_rank()`

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH Tmp AS
  (SELECT Id,
          Name,
          SUM(Score) AS total_score
   FROM Mytable
   GROUP BY Id,
            Name)
SELECT Name,   Id,
       MAX(total_score) AS max_score
FROM Tmp
GROUP BY Name,id
ORDER BY max_score DESC
```

Try this. Hope this will help.

Comment: Because, if we need to have `id` in `select`, you either have to put it in an aggregate function(`max, sum, count` etc) or put it in `group by`. The same the error was saying. We can have only those columns in `select` which are either wrapped in aggregated function or which are present in `group by`

Comment: If multiple `id` are having similar `Name` then your answer will not work. @d.b If every `Name` is unique then this answer will work fine.

Comment: Moreover your second `select` will return exact same number of rows that are returned by `Tmp` because `Tmp` is having unique record per `id` & `Name` and use `GROUP BY` again on it will have no effect on record.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about performance of below query but we can use `window functions` to get `maximum` value from data `partition`.

```
SELECT
        Id,
        Name,
        SUM(Score) AS total_score,
        MAX(SUM(Score)) OVER(Partition by Name) AS max_score
FROM Mytable
GROUP BY Id, Name;
```

Tested -

```
declare @Mytable table (id int, name varchar(10), score int);
insert into @Mytable values
(1,'abc', 100),
(2,'abc', 200),
(3,'def', 300),
(3,'def', 400),
(4,'pqr', 500);
```

Output -

```
Id  Name   total_score  max_score
1   abc    100          200
2   abc    200          200
3   def    700          700
4   pqr    500          500
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH Tmp AS
 (
 SELECT Id,
          Name,
          SUM(Score) AS total_score
   FROM Mytable
   GROUP BY Id,
            NAME
 )
SELECT Name,   Id,
       MAX(total_score) AS max_score
FROM Tmp
GROUP BY Name,id
ORDER BY max_score DESC
```

Note:- If we are using aggregate function then we have to use other column as Group By....

In your case you are using SUM(Score) as aggregate function then we to use other column as Group by ...

Comment: Your second `select` will return exact same number of rows that are returned by `Tmp` because `Tmp` is having unique record per `id` & `Name` and use `GROUP BY` again on it will have no effect on record.

Answer (score 1):

You can select [DENSE_RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with `total_score` column and then select records with `Rank = 1`. This will work for those also when there are multiple `Name` which are having same `total_score`.

```
WITH Tmp AS
  (SELECT Id,
          Name,
          SUM(Score) AS total_score
   FROM Mytable
   GROUP BY Id, Name)
SELECT Id, 
       Name,
       total_score AS max_score
FROM (SELECT Id, 
           Name,
           total_score,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY total_score DESC) AS Rank
    FROM Tmp) AS Tmp2
WHERE Rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```
select id,name,max(total_score) over (partition by name)  max_score from (
select id,name,sum(score) as total_score from YOURTABLE
group by id,name
) t
```